# Text box in aspx where user should allowed to enter ALL as text or any number for 1-100

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to validate a textbox entered data where the user should be allowed to enter 'ALL' as text or any number for 1-100 no other text data should be accepted.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]. Simply put, you need to make an effort of your own as SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fairly crude script that should make the background of the input field green if the answer is acceptable, white if it's not certain, and red if it is unacceptable.

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const text = e.target.value;
  switch(text.length) {
    case 0:
      e.target.style = "background: white";
      return;
    case 1:
      const p1 = /\d/;
      if(p1.test(text) && text != "0")
        e.target.style = "background: lightgreen";
      else if(text == "A" || text == "0")
        e.target.style = "background: white";
      else
        e.target.style = "background: red";
      return;
    case 2:
      const p2 = /\d\d/;
      if(p2.test(text) && text != "00")
        e.target.style = "background: lightgreen";
      else if(text == "AL" || text == "00")
        e.target.style = "background: white";
      else
        e.target.style = "background: red";
      return;
    case 3:
      const p3 = /0\d\d/;
      if(text != "000" && p3.test(text) || text == "100" || text == "ALL")
        e.target.style = "background: lightgreen";
      else
        e.target.style = "background: red";
      return;
  }
});
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const num = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if ((num >= 1 && num <= 100) || e.target.value === "ALL") console.log("Ok!");
  else console.log("Bad!");
});
```

```html
<div>Type a number between 1-100 or ALL:</div>
<input id="input" type="text" maxlength="3">
```